# How to filter two json object lists by their properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to compare two different list of json objects by their properties. For example, One list contains User objects and the other list contains Account list with userId. I need to filter the user list which ids are not in the account list. I know how to do it manually, but It adds a lot of boilerplate code. Is there any library out there i can us to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/)

```
var notInTheAccountList = _.filter(users, function(user){ return _.isEmpty(_.findWhere(accounts, {userId: user.id})); });
```